# RecyclerView, show last message i send on recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm having a problem with this code, I created a personal chat, but when I send a message the RecyclerView does not show automatically the last message sent but I have to scroll down, how can I make sure that automatically displays the last message?

public class ChatListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Activity mActivity;
private DatabaseReference mDataBaseReference;
private String mDisplayName;
private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> mDataSnapshot;


private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener () {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String s) {

        mDataSnapshot.add (dataSnapshot);
        notifyDataSetChanged ();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};




public ChatListAdapter(Activity activity, DatabaseReference ref, String name){

    mActivity = activity;
    mDataBaseReference = ref.child ("messaggi");
    mDisplayName = name;
    mDataSnapshot = new ArrayList <> ();

    mDataBaseReference.addChildEventListener (mListener);
}

public class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView autore;
    TextView messaggio;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;


    public ChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);

        autore = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tv_autore);
        messaggio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tv_messaggio);
        params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) autore.getLayoutParams ();
    }
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mActivity.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.chat_msg_row, parent, false);
    ChatViewHolder vh = new ChatViewHolder (v);

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatViewHolder holder,int position) {

    DataSnapshot snapshot = mDataSnapshot.get (position);

    Messaggio msg = snapshot.getValue (Messaggio.class);

    holder.autore.setText (msg.getAutore ());
    holder.messaggio.setText (msg.getMessaggio ());

    boolean sonoIo = msg.getAutore ().equals (mDisplayName);
    setChatItemStyle(sonoIo, holder);


}

private void setChatItemStyle(boolean sonoIo, ChatViewHolder holder){
    if(sonoIo){

        holder.params.gravity = Gravity.END;
        holder.autore.setTextColor (Color.GREEN);
        holder.messaggio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_msg_bg);


    }else{

        holder.params.gravity = Gravity.START;
        holder.autore.setTextColor (Color.CYAN);
        holder.messaggio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out_msg_bg);

    }

    holder.autore.setLayoutParams (holder.params);
    holder.messaggio.setLayoutParams (holder.params);


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSnapshot.size ();
}

public void clean(){
    mDataBaseReference.removeEventListener (mListener);
}
```

}

Comment: Try with `notifyItemInserted` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: it ask me the int on notifyItemInserted(  what i need to write here ?  );  and create me private void notifyItemInseted(){}

Comment: In your case you are inserting at the end correct? So you can give notifyItemInserted(mDataSnapshot.size()-1)

Comment: everything is correct, but I have to keep scrolling down even with these changes

Comment: Then after notifyingItemInserted, do this.
`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mDataSnapshot.size() - 1);`


One more suggestion is that, DO NOT maintain dataset outside the scope of adapter class. It might look easier but it will cause problems with consistency. Instead pass the data set to adapter through constructor and add a method to replace dataset and notify adapter inside it.

Comment: with this  code the app crashedd     private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener () {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String s) {

            mDataSnapshot.add (dataSnapshot);
            //notifyDataSetChanged ();
            notifyItemInserted (mDataSnapshot.size()-1);

            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mDataSnapshot.size()-1);

        }

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: sorry what do you means for stack trace?

Comment: I meant the error log

Comment: @MARDOCHMA please see my answer and mark correct if it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

You can set `stackFromEnd` to be true on your `LinearLayoutManager`. If your chat messages are coming back most recent first, you can also reverse on the manager rather than in data. Then to auto scroll on dataset changed, simply set `android:transcriptMode` to `normal` (scroll only if already at bottom) or `alwaysScroll` (always scroll to bottom after a change) on your RecyclerView xml.

```
boolean reverseLayout = true; // Or false if your data is already reversed
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, reverseLayout);
manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: do I have to enter all this code too? in which part of the code I posted?

Comment: This is set on your recycler view. You do not have a reference in your code, so you will need to apply as it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a recycler view to populate messages.

So here it is

Variable Declaration

```
private RecyclerView rvChat;
```

onCreate

```
rvChat = findViewById(R.id.a_individual_chat_rv_chat);
```

onChildAdded (After notifyDataSetChanged)

```
rvChat.smoothScrollToPosition(rvChat.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```

Comment: I have tested this is working on a fragment-adapter-model construct for recycler view.